# Is there an R program that can turn a table of binary values into a stacked barplot

Tags: r

I have a data-set which has a few columns that have binary values, a similar data-set is in the table below.

| Name | UserID | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | 1000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Ben | 1001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Katie | 1011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Lily | 1012 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Penny | 1016 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sam | 1019 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Is there a way to extract the columns with binary values and create a stacked bar-plot such as the one below:

[image: Barplot]

I started by using the pivot_longer function, but I am absolutely lost after this:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(Week.1:Week.4)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Thanks. I'll look into pivot_longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out **tidyverse** and **dplyr** library for data wrangling.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

## Creating the dataframe
df = data.frame(Name = c('Alan','Ben','Katie','Lily','Pen'),
                UserID = 1000:1004,
                Week1 = c(1,0,1,1,1),
                Week2 = c(1,1,1,1,0),
                Week3 = c(1,0,1,0,0),
                Week4 = c(0,0,1,0,0))

## Data Wrangling
df = df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(Name,UserID),names_to = 'Week', values_to = 'count') %>% ## Columns to rows
  group_by(Week,count) %>% ## Grouping
  summarise(cnt = n()) ## Aggregation

## Creating a stacked bar chart
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week, y =cnt, fill = as.factor(count)))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+ylab('Count')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','green'))+theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: If you believe this answer solved your problem, please consider clicking the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. This will help other community users who are struggling with the similar issue.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, after using your code on my own dataset, I was able to make a satisfactory barplot, however, the weeks are ordered weirdly, the weeks are ordered - 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,13,12,11,1. I would prefer it in ascending order. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: To reorder the weeks, just use the following syntax before using the ggplot:                                                                      df$weeks <- factor(df$weeks , levels= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,13))